# SQLAlchemy - Association Table Relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, associations, fastapi, model-associations

I have the following tables: Workstation and Parameters.

I want to associate the Workstation with the Parameters, using a WorkstationParameter table that also contains the value of the parameter, using SQLAlchemy.

Is there any way that when getting a workstation from the database, all the parameters come with it?
Currently I have {"name": "workstation", "id": 1}. I added the association using WorkstationParameter but I don't know if it is correct because I was expecting to get {"parameters": [], "name": "workstation", "id": 1}

I tried to replicate this: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object

Comment: You need to show the actual way you set the relationship up

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could make it lazy and it potentially wouldn't add the `parameters` key. But I'm guessing

Comment: I added the lazy and the solution I got was to create a new schema and convert the current "workstation" to the schema I wanted. I'll provide more information